# How to hide reusable svg with filter that has filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"

Tags: html, css

I want to hide a reusable svg, height: 0 and width: 0 does the job, but when I have a filter with filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" it hides the svg that is using the filter. How can I hide the reusable svg without hiding the svg that is using the filter?

```css
.reusable-svgs{
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
svg{
  overflow: visible;
}
div{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
rect{
  filter: url(#shadow);
  fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<svg class="reusable-svgs">
  <filter id="shadow" width="200%" height="200%" y="-60%" x="-60%" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <feDropShadow dx="0.4" dy="0" stdDeviation="4" />
  </filter>
</svg>
<div>
  <svg viewbox="0 0 20 20"><rect height="20" width="20"/></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting your height: 0 and width: 0 is the answer to hiding an svg that uses `filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`  ... So what exactly is the issue?

Comment: @John No I don't want to hide the svg that is using the filter I want to hide only the reusable svg. In my example I have 2 svgs only 1 should be hidden

Comment: position:absolute + top:-1000vw should be enough to take it off screen without scrollbars.